# How to fix osintgram pip install -r requirements.txt command error

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Osintram, and whenever I run the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command, the following error message appears:

```
pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. The following dependency conflicts are caused by this behaviour.
crackmapexec 5.4.0 requires aioconsole<0.4.0,>=0.3.3, but you have aioconsole 0.3.1 which is incompatible.                                                
crackmapexec 5.4.0 requires minikerberos==0.3.3, but you have minikerberos 0.3.5 which is incompatible.                                                   
crackmapexec 5.4.0 requires neo4j<5.0.0,>=4.1.1, but you have neo4j 5.2.dev0 which is incompatible.                                                       
crackmapexec 5.4.0 requires pypsrp<0.8.0,>=0.7.0, but you have pypsrp 0.5.0 which is incompatible.                                                        
crackmapexec 5.4.0 requires requests>=2.27.1, but you have requests 2.24.0 which is incompatible.                                                         
crackmapexec 5.4.0 requires xmltodict<0.13.0,>=0.12.0, but you have xmltodict 0.13.0 which is incompatible.                                               
pyppeteer 1.0.1 requires pyee<9.0.0,>=8.1.0, but you have pyee 9.0.4 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt is very clear that there is a conflict in the versions of your dependency libraries. Please carefully check the versions of your dependency libraries. If you need detailed help, you can paste the content `requirements.txt` file into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the `requirements.txt` file, you can specify the version of each package that will be installed.

The error message states that:

- **aioconsole** version should be greater than or equal to `0.3.3` and less than `0.4.0`
- **minikerberos** version should be exactly `0.3.3`
- **neo4j** version should be greater than or equal to `4.1.1` and less than `5.0.0`
- **pypsrp** version should be greater than or equal to `0.7.0` and less than `0.8.0`
- **requests** version should be greater than or equal to `2.27.1`
- **xmltodict** version should be greater than or equal to `0.12.0` and less than `0.13.0`
- **pyee** version should be greater than or equal to `8.1.0` and less than `9.0.0`

Hence, it is likely that your `requirements.txt` file needs to be updated as shown below:

```
aioconsole>=0.3.3,<0.4.0
minikerberos==0.3.3
neo4j>=4.1.1,<5.0.0
pypsrp>=0.7.0,<0.8.0
requests>=2.27.1
xmltodict>=0.12.0,<0.13.0
pyee>=8.1.0,<9.0.0
crackmapexec
pyppeteer
```

Note that the `crackmapexec` package requires a Python version greater than or equal to `3.7.0` and less than `4.0.0`.